# WhatsApp with asterisk but not bold

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In WhatsApp how to send *something* with asterisk before and after the word without getting bold?

Answer (score 1):

From [WhatsApp help](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/26000002):

> There is no option to disable this feature.

However you can type a space between asterisk and the first letter after it and MAYBE the text will not be bold on the receiver side (this "hack" depends on the smartphone model and does not work on iPhones).

Answer (score 0):

I found this out by accident trying formatting out for the first time:
If the first asterisk immediately follows an emoji with no space between them, then the asterisks appear verbatim instead of making the word bold.

e.g.

(punching fist emoji)*BOOM* appears as (punching fist emoji)*BOOM*

but

(punching fist emoji) *BOOM* appears as (punching fist emoji) **BOOM**

I am using WhatsApp Messenger Version 2.17.24 on a BQ Aquaris E5 4G with Android 6.0.1